# are there other possible ways to use groovy in Eclipse except plugin

Tags: windows, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse Mars 4.5.0 IDE and I would like to do some Groovy project.Adding groovy as a plugin is not working, because I am not able to connect to http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/p2.index. In fact even simple update are not working. There is always some connection time out like connection to http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/update/4.5/content.xml.

However I do have groovy installed on my system. Is there anyway I could tell the IDE to use the system groovy? Or is it possible to download the plugin and manually add it to the IDE? I am using windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The groovy compiler delivered by the plugin is [patched](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Updating-the-groovy-in-groovy-eclipse) and therefore I don't think it is possible to use an external groovy compiler.

If you're behind a proxy, try to configure eclipse with manual proxy settings.

At least the 4.6 and 4.7 snapshot update site works well for me ATM, but when i had access problems, I downloaded the last working build from the [ci server](https://build.spring.io/browse/GRECLIPSE) mentioned in the wiki:

e.g. E45 build and publish -> #393 -> Artifacts -> Zipped Update Site

and used it as an update site (add.. -> archive).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the response. I will try it and give a feedback